# Factorize Quintic Polynomial

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials

Factorize the quintic polynomial $P(x) = x^5 + 2x^4 -x -2$ into a product of irreducible linear and quadratic factors what are the roots of $p$?

Hi, i got this question in a worksheet but my text book doesn't have anything about quintic polynomials in it. if anybody could help me that would be great!

Comment: use the rational root theorem

Comment: $x^5-x+2(x^4-1)=x(x^4-1)+2(x^4-1)=(x+2)(x^4-1)=\cdots$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Divisors of $-2$ are $$1,-1,-2,2$$ and you will find all roots if they are integers

Comment: **"... if they are integers"**. We have been fortunate here that all the roots are integers.

Answer (score 0):

let us see the root of the $P(x)=0$. first try the factor of $\frac{-2}{1}=-2$, if $x=1,-1,-2$, the $P(x)=0$, so $P(x)$ must have factor $(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)$.

then use division, $\frac{P(x)}{(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)} = x^2+1$.

so $P(x) = (x-1)(x+1)(x+2)(x^2+1)$.